# Двумерные массивы с++

Tags: c++

Помогите исправить ошибки.Задача:Для заданной матрицы размером 8 на 8 найти такие k, что k-я строка матрицы совпадает с k-м столбцом.
Найти сумму элементов в тех строках, которые содержат хотя бы один отрицательный элемент.Помогите исправить ошибки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{   srand(time(0));
int A[8][8],k,i,j,S=0,z;
for (i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    for ( j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        A[i][j]=rand()%20-5;
    }
}
for (i=0;i<8;i++)
for (j=0;j<8;j++)
{
    cout<<setw(8) <<A[i][j]<<"  ";
}
for (i=0;i<k;i++)
{
k=0;
for (j=0;j<k;j++)
if(A[i][j]==A[j][i])
k++;
if(k==3)
cout<<"k="<<i;
}
for (i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        if(A[i][j]<0)
        {
            S+=A[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nSuma elementov v "<<i+1<<" = "<<S<<endl;
    S=0;
}
getch ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: в чём конкретно проблема, приведите вашу попытку решить задачу.

Comment: "найти такие k, что k-я строка матрицы совпадает с k-м столбцом" - не могу понять,что от меня требуют

Comment: Видимо написать исходный код программы. Представите Ваше решение. Посмотрим.

Comment: ну формально:  print K | A x : m[k][x] = m[x][k]

Comment: @Yaroslav Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу составлял человек, которому нельзя работать преподавателем. Имеется в виду, что последовательность элементов, составляющих столбец (сверху вниз) совпадает с последовательностью элементов, составляющих строку (слева направо). Так вот, если первая строка подобным образом совпадает с первым столбцом, то `k=1`. Если вторая со вторым, то `k=2` и т. д. Найти все такие значения `k`.

Предполагается, что матрица числовая, возможно даже из целых чисел.

Пример

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
3 4 0 4 5 3 3 1
4 5 3 4 6 4 3 2
5 6 3 6 5 7 6 2
6 7 2 5 6 6 5 3
7 8 3 4 1 6 2 1
8 9 1 2 2 3 1 5
```

k = 1, 2, 8 (если отсчёт идет от 1, а не от нуля).

Ответ на второй вопрос - ноль.

Comment: Но ведь матрица может содержать отрицательные числа, тогда на второй вопрос нужно искать сумму в строке

Comment: Второй вопрос идет отдельным пунктом, автор просто их слепил в один и чуток не разобрался )